# Derivate of a matrix vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to calculate the derivates with respect to W and h for this function
$$
f(W, h) =  ||\frac{Wh}{||Wh||}-y||^2
$$
W is a matrix, h and y are column wise vectors.

I got
$$
dh = 2 - \frac{2y'Wh}{||Wh||}
$$
Is it correct?
And I'm confused on dW.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Please elaborate on the definition of 'derivative' that you are using, and please write down your derivation based on this definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), which as a nice exposition [here, by Prof. Barnes](http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf).

One way to approach such problems is by components:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}f 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}\left|\left|\frac{Wh}{||Wh||_2}-y\,\right|\right|_2^2\\[1mm]
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}\sum_i\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]^2\\
&= \sum_i2\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]\frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]\\
&= \sum_i2\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]
\left( \left[\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell\right]
\frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}||Wh||_2^{-1} + ||Wh||_2^{-1}W_{ij} \right)\\
\end{align}
Simplifying the inner term:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}||Wh||_2^{-1}
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}(h^TW^TWh)^{-1/2}\\
&= \frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}[h^TW^TWh]\right)^{-3/2} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}\left[\sum_s (Wh)_s^2\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\left[\sum_s \frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right)^2\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\left[\sum_s2\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial h_j}\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right)\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\left[\sum_s2\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right) W_{sj}\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
\end{align}
Similarly, we get:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}||Wh||_2^{-1}
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\left[\sum_s \frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right)^2\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\left[\sum_s2\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right)\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\left[\sum_s2\left(\sum_t W_{st}h_t\right) \frac{\partial W_{sb}}{\partial W_{ab}}h_b\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\left[2\left(\sum_t W_{at}h_t\right) h_b\right]\right)^{-3/2} \\
\end{align}
And for the matrix derivative:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}f 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}\left|\left|\frac{Wh}{||Wh||_2}-y\,\right|\right|_2^2\\[1mm]
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}\sum_i\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]^2\\
&= \sum_i2\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]\\
&= \sum_i2\left[ ||Wh||_2^{-1}\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell - y_i \right]
\left( \left[\sum_\ell W_{i\ell}h_\ell\right]
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ab}}||Wh||_2^{-1} + ||Wh||_2^{-1}
h_b\delta_{ia}
 \right)\\ 
\end{align}
where $\delta_{ia}$ is the Kronecker delta.

So you have the components of your desired derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial h} = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_n}\right)
$$ 
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial W} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{11}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1n}}\\ \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{n1}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{nn}}
\end{bmatrix} $$